# Vue js fails to render the component in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-component

Am new to laravel and VUe js, after a fresh installation of laravel 5.4 it comes with an example vue component that am trying to render in a blade file but it fails

IN the folder `resources/assets/js/components/Example.vue` i have

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
      Testing component
   </div>
</template>

 <script>
   export default {

    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
   }
 </script>
```

Then i the folder `resources/assets/js/app.js` i have

```
  Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

  const app = new Vue({
       el: '#app'
  });
```

Then in the welcome.blade.php i have

```
<div id="app">
   <example></example>
 </div>
```

THe above component is not rendered, i have also run

```
npm run watch
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: `<div id="app"` - close it with `>`

Comment: That was a typo mistake in stackoverflow but in the code its closed

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/65/ the code itself works fine. Try not requiring component, but `import` it like this: `import Example from './.../Example.vue'` and declare component as `Vue.component('example', Example)`

Comment: If you're using chrome browser then you can install chrome extension Vue.js devtools to find out the problem. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Comment: THanks wostex ive figured out the reason was because when using the default welcome.blade.php it doesnt include the layout file which contains the compiled app.js file, after running make:auth now it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for the future visitors to this question the problem was that the vue.js was not loaded on the page where the code was written. So always make sure that you check if you are loading your libraries where you need them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this particular example. I have found that in the default welcome.blade.php file  that VueJS requires and the VueJS library are not present. Hence what I did was:

In file welcome.blade.php add the bolded lines:

```
<body>
    **<div id="app">**
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            @if (Route::has('login'))
                <div class="top-right links">
                    @auth
                        <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>
                        <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
                    @endauth
                </div>
            @endif

            <div class="content">
                <div class="title m-b-md">
                    SAGACE
                </div>
                <example></example>
        </div>
    **</div>**
    <!-- Scripts -->
    **<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>**
</body>
```

Hence this view will have access to the app.js where all components are and now can be rendered properly, as pointed out by [lewis4u](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2502731/lewis4u)